# Extracting data from an html table and building a string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have the following HTML table:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <th>Actions</th><th>Contact Type</th><th>Contact</th><th>Call Order</th>  <th>Text</th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="rulesegment_1">
       <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeruleset"></td>
       <td class="contact_type" id="contact_type1">6</td>
       <td id="contact_details1">1234</td>
       <td class="call_order" id="call_order1">1</td>
       <td class="textm" id="textm1">false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rulesegment_2">
       <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeruleset"></td>
       <td class="contact_type" id="contact_type2">4</td>
       <td id="contact_details2">123424234</td>
       <td class="call_order" id="call_order2">1</td>
       <td class="textm" id="textm2">false</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I need to extract all the data from the table and end up with a string that looks like this:

```
  "6,1234,1,false~4,123424234,1,false~"
```

What's the best way to do this? 
Is there any method / function in jQuery that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
// select all the 'td' elements:
var str = $('td').filter(function(){
    /* filter those elements to keep only those the
       length of whose trimmed text is greater than zero:
    */
    return $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0;
}).map(function(){
    // trim the text of those kept 'td' elements, and return it
    return $.trim($(this).text());
/* store it in an array (using 'get()'), and join those array
   elements together with commas:
/*
}).get().join(',');

console.log(str);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9hWv4/).

Updated the above to include the tilde (`~`):

```
var str = $('td').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0;
}).map(function(){
    var self = $(this),
        text = self.text();
    return !self.next().length ? text + '~' : text;
}).get().join(',');

console.log(str);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9hWv4/1/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)
- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: if i wanted to specify the table name, where would i do that?  This code needs to run when the submit button on my form is clicked. I've tried replace (this) with the table name... but it's giving me grief

Comment: If, by 'name' you mean `id`, then: `$('#tableID td')` (instead of just `$('td')`).

Comment: David, that's awesome!  the only issue is that I need to prevent the extra comma that is include before the second record.  For example, your sample code produces this type of data for me:  "6,4442,1,false~,4,93923423,2,true~"
But I would like  "6,4442,1,false~4,93923423,2,true~"
I'm trying to review your code to see if I can fix it myself too... thanks.

Comment: Did you try the second demo that I posted, which removes any cells without text (using the `filter()` method), before creating the array?

Answer (score 0):

Just chain your $.map calls, for processing rows and then cells, like this:

```
// Get all the tr's that have an id attribute
$.map($('tr[id]'),function(node){

    // Inside of each row, exclude the cells that have an input.
    return $.map($('td', node).not(':has(input)'), function(td){
         return $(td).text();
    }).join(','); // Join the text with a comma
}).join('~'); // Join the rows with a tilde
```

Here's the test:

http://jsbin.com/avUb/1/edit